# Cant test $status in nginx config with fastcgi_pass to php-fpm - status is 000

Tags: php, nginx

We have a rather busy site with nginx, php-fpm (7) on Ubuntu 16.04.

We would like to store logs only in case an error happens in php (http status code 404, 500, ...), so we setup this in the server config:

```
set $logit 0;
  if ($status ~ ^[45]) {
        set $logit 1;
        }
 access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx.access condensed if=$logit;
```

but we get no errors stored :(.

When we enable debug mode, we see this :

```
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script if
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script if: false
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script var
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script var: "000"
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script regex: "^[45]"
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [notice] 28852#28852: *7258 "^[45]" does not match "000", client: 87.138.160.167, server: xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx"
2016/08/01 16:55:37 [debug] 28852#28852: *7258 http script if
```

so, for some reason, in the if statement, $status is evaluated as "000"

when I add this for debugging:

```
add_header test-debug $status always;
```

i get `test-debug:404`

i guess the problem is that this is a proxy for php-fpm, so the status is only set later by the response from php-fpm, but cant find what variable to test for ?